# How to show two lines as one item in jquery autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

Here is the part of my code

```
   // Auto Complete Handler
        $("#NameInput").autocomplete("/Data/GetNames", {
            cacheLength: 25,
            minChars: 4,
            delay: 50,
            scrollHeight: 400,
            autoFill: true
        });
```

Right now, this piece of code brings a set of names from c# and displays. Lets say i want to append few properties to name like, `"Hyundai\n, Verna", "Honda\n, Brio", "Maruti\n, Swift"`. In this format my c# code is giving the data to Autocomplete, here autocomplete rendering each string as 2 different item. and selection is also happening once for Hyundai and once for verna. Thats wrong.

I want to display each string as single item and i want to change the color & font of 2nd line of each item. How to do this?

Comment: show us a retunred json string.

Comment: Simply i m returning, return builder.ToString(); like this

Answer (score 2):

This stackoverflow link might be helpful for you.
This explains how to use your own custom data formats in frontend and displays by simply overriding the default focus and select actions.

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39893804/5485645)

Example:

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<div>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

```js
  $( function() {
    var projects = [
      {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
      }
    ];
 
    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: projects,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
        $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );
 
        return false;
      }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<div>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  } );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Custom data and display</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #project-label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  #project-icon {
    float: left;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
  }
  #project-description {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 
<div id="project-label">Select a project (type "j" for a start):</div>
<img id="project-icon" src="images/transparent_1x1.png" class="ui-state-default" alt="">
<input id="project">
<input type="hidden" id="project-id">
<p id="project-description"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the template like this

```
$("#NameInput").autocomplete("/Data/GetNames", {
    //your params
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
```

Comment: Its telling Data is undefined. Do we need to return JSON data to work?, can we return a simple list to make it work

Comment: I'm getting this error, 'autocomplete(...).data(...)' is null or not an object