# PHP json_encode in autocomplete

Tags: php, json

I have

```
<form action='' method='post'>
  City name <br /><br />
  <input type='text' name='search' value='' class='auto'>
</form>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1
    });

  });
</script>
```

This is autocomplete. And now I receive fields from MySQL base in search.php file:

```
if(isset($_GET['term']))
    {
        $city = array();
        $airport = array();
        $citysearchsql = mysqli_query(db(),"SELECT * FROM citycode WHERE cityname LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%' ");
        while($citysearchresult = mysqli_fetch_array($citysearchsql))
        {



            $airnamesql = mysqli_query(db(),"SELECT * FROM airports WHERE citycode='".$citysearchresult['citycode']."' ");
            while($airnameresult = mysqli_fetch_array($airnamesql))
            {
                $airport[] = $airnameresult['airportname'];
            }
            $city[] = $citysearchresult['cityname'];
        }




        echo json_encode($city);

    }
```

Base has two tables `citycode` and `airports`. When user writes city name, need to show city name and under city name show airport name, like here

http://joxi.ru/krD8oY1u0Nb0kr

I cant do it with `json_encode`.

any ideas, anybody can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimized to be just one query:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $city = array();
        $citysearchsql = mysqli_query(db(),"SELECT a.airportname, c.cityname FROM citycode c INNER JOIN airports a ON c.citycode = a.citycode WHERE c.cityname LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%' ORDER BY c.citycode ASC");
        while($citysearchresult = mysqli_fetch_array($citysearchsql))
        {
            if (!in_array($citysearchresult['cityname'], $city)) {
                $city[] = $citysearchresult['cityname'];
            }
            $city[] = $citysearchresult['airportname'];   
        }
        echo json_encode($city);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution are working, but I need to stylize it somehow, like here: http://joxi.ru/krD8oY1u0Nb0kr

I am already tried to use html tags, like &nbsp, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Get all required elements in array then you can use your own custom data formats  in frontend and displays by simply overriding the default focus and select actions.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete()
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( item.label )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

[Check this link for demo example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can... just merge tables

```
echo json_encode(array_merge($city, $airport));
```